# How to get the top level hierarchy as separate column

Tags: sql, sql-server, presto

I have a requirement where data looks as shown below in the table where `PL-135` is the top level with children `21-001`, `210-002`, `PL-76`. In turn, `PL-76` is parent of `25-001` and `25-002` but child of `PL-135`.

[image]

I need above input as below Output.

[image]

Also data may consists more than 2 levels of hierarchy. It would be great if I get the answer without recursion as PrestoDB doesn't allow recursion.

Comment: *"It would be great if I get the answer without recursion as PrestoDB don't Allow recursion."* You'll need to switch to a `hierarchyid` then. To navigate through a hierarchy using a different data type, such as like you've used a `varchar`, (in SQL Server)you have to use a recusive Common Table Expression (rCTE) to iterate through each "level".

Comment: Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Do you know how many levels deep the data goes? I suspect you are going to need dynamic sql here as recursion like this is rarely a set number of levels.

Comment: @seanLange I think not more than 4 levels.

Comment: @ThomA basically in PrestoDB we don't have hierarchyid concept.

Comment: Can you create a `VIEW` in SQL Server, which is defined using an rCTE, and then query that from Presto?

Comment: @ThomA I have limitation while working on prod environment.

Comment: A limitation of what? That you also can't `CREATE` `VIEW`s? Then speak to someone who has permissions to perform DDL statements and have them create you a `VIEW` you can query? Your comment doesn't actually answer my question on if you can use a `VIEW` or not.